# Git commit directory in pycharm using keyboard shortcut

Tags: git, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts, commit

In PyCharm, one can commit single directories or files by right-clicking on them in the "Project" pane, and then choosing "Git->Commit Directory..." from the context menu (see below). How can I do exactly this using a keyboard shortcut (while the file/directory is highlighted in the "Project" pane)?

[image: here]

Comment: user1157767's answer is actually the right one, I suggest you update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you looking for is the `Check In` in the PyCharm keymap.

If you go Settings -> Keymap ->  *Search for `Check In`*

Assign a shortcut for the Git -> `Check In`. eg. Ctrl+Shift+O

Now if you navigate to the directory or file you want to commit and click
Ctrl+Shift+O  the Commit Changes window will open.

*Note: This is an existing naming [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-50642).*

Answer (score 4):

Its `Ctrl + K` to commit
and `Ctrl + Shift + K` to push
Found it under Help > Key map reference

Comment: Not strictly true.  `Ctrl + K` opens the 'Commit Changes' window for the *entire project*, not just the selected directory